# Notified property not "updated" in the UI

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a model composed of three classes: A, B and C.
A has an ObservableCollection of B, B has an ObservableCollection of C.
C has a reference (not observable.. I don't think is needed) to its parent (B), and B has a reference to A.
Each attribute of A, B and C notifies its changes.

I then have a Model class which "keeps track" of all the objects allocated. So it has an ObservableCollection of A, of B and of C (the only one that is required is for the As; I keep the lists for B and C only for faster reference).

My UI has a custom control: it has a ViewModel. The view has a list. Its ItemSources is bound to its ViewModel to an observablecollection named sensors. This ObservableCollection is of RowViewModel. Each RowViewModel keeps a reference to a C object.

My application loads the Model (creating A, B, C objects) and then sets the list of the view by calling this method (maybe this is the problem?)

```
public void setSensors(IList<C> list)
        {
            this.sensors.Clear();
            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (var row in list)
                    this.sensors.Add(new RowViewModel(row));
            }
        }
```

The problem is that if I modify a property of my C object, this is not reflected on the UI.

Someone can help me?
Thank you

Francesco

EDIT: (SOLVED)
thanks to your answers I checked my code and changed one thing: instead of binding my UI element to its ViewModel (and the viewModel simply "redirect" the call to the model property), I directly bind the UI to the real property, and it works!!
So... in MVVM I cannot use "shortcuts"??.. or if I use them I should register for notification of the property and "propagates" them?

Comment: Are your property changed events firing correctly ?

Comment: well.. i think yes. I put a breakpoint in my "NotifyPropertyChanged" and it enters it

Comment: try checking if someone is listening to those events. If the correct objects are effectively listening, well i dont know :/

Comment: Ok.. they were not listened... now I solved!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10335235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your UI isn't updated, because it's binded to `RowViewModel` object, not to `C`. So, you should subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of `C` in your `RowViewModel`'s constructor, and notify about those changes through `RowViewModel.PropertyChanged`. By the way, can you provide an example of binding in your UI?

**UPDATED:**

An example of "proxying" `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public class Model: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _YourProperty;
  public string YourProperty
  {
    get { return _YourProperty; }
    set
    {
      if (_YourProperty == value) return;
      _YourProperty = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("YourProperty");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Model _Model;

  public ViewModel(Model model)
  {
    _Model = model;
    _Model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
  }

  public string YourProperty
  {
    get { return _Model.YourProperty; }
  }

  private void OnModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.PropertyName == "YourProperty")
      RaisePropertyChanged("YourProperty");
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

You can read also http://george.softumus.com/2011/10/inotifypropertychanged-and-magic.html - how to avoid using "magic strings" (hardcoded constants) as property names.

Comment: I don't have reputation to add answer.. so... My Row UI is made in this way:

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Name="isOnlineBox" IsChecked="{Binding isOnline}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="25" Height="25"/> 

the isOnline property is in the RowViewModel:

    public Boolean isOnline
            {
                get
                {
                    return myC.b.a.isOnline;
                }
            }


My doubt is... b and a properties are not "observable", but is online yes.

Comment: I don't see any need for proxying property change event at all ad your property is set in constructor. And it is not changing. This is not necessary in fact it is more harmful, you are updating view model's model everytime property of model is changing, this will cause silverlight to refresh everything for no reason.

Comment: OK, very simple example - you have model with 2 properties like `Name` and `Version` and want to see it in your view as `<Name> [v.<Version>]` (e.g. `SuperTool [v.2]`). Proxying property is easy way to do it (in WPF you can use `IMultiValueConverter`, but Silvelight hasn't it). And there are actually a lot of another examples, when you want to use proxying. Of course, almost always you can use some another technique. But it's very disputable question what is the best way in every specific scenario. So it's better to know that proxying exists, and it's your own choice - use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Rules for Model to update UI Automatically :-

1. Your Property of type Collection must be of type ObservableCollection
2. Your Model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
3. Every property of your model, unless it is string or value type, must of type that should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
4. If your value Property of type Collection changes, it should fire PropertyChanged for name of property even if it is derived from ObservableCollection

Comment: Most likely 4th rule is not followed by people, because they assume that change of collection instance is same as adding/removing item in collection, otherwise you will have to check for binding warnings in VS Output Window.